# IDE Visual Studio code, word wrap não muda de 80

Tags: visual-studio-code, configuração, editor-de-texto

[Meu settings.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9WomS.png)

Ele aparece a margem de 150, mas quebra a linha no 80 ainda, já troquei em todas as opções de "editor.wordWrap" e "editor.wordWrapColunm", mesmo assim continua no 80